# Track Changes, View "Final" in Google Docs?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

Google Docs has a feature called "Suggesting" which is similar to Microsoft Word's "Track Changes".

In Microsoft Word, once you have made your changes there is an option to view the file with "Final".

"Final" will show you the document as it would be if all of the proposed changes are agreed.

Is there something similar to this in Google Docs? The only other option I can find in Google Docs is "Viewing" mode, but this does the opposite of Microsoft Word's "Final". "Viewing" just shows you the document if all of the proposed changes were not agreed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- activate **Editing** or **Suggesting** mode
- go to **Tools**
- select **Review suggested edits**
- select **Show suggested edits**
- select **Preview "Accept all"**

[image: 1]

Comment: This is nice. Though it is very useful in Word that you can edit the "final" version directly. So you can work as if you edited without tracking making it a lot less messy. Seems you cannot edit in gdocs when in preview mode.

Comment: To get around the fact that you can't edit on the Preview "accept all" screen, you can bring up two windows of the same doc side by side. You can read the Preview "accept all" version which is free of all the track changes clutter, and then when you spot required edits you work on the other version with track changes visible.

Answer (score -1):

> In Microsoft Word, once you have made your changes there is an option to view the file with "Final".
> "Final" will show you the document as it would be if all of the proposed changes are agreed.
> Is there something similar to this in Google Docs?

I see an option in Google Docs that offers the same function as "final" in Microsoft Word:
(in Italian)

> Strumenti > Esamina modifiche suggerite >> Visualizza un'anteprima di "Accetta tutti"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I edited my contribution after <Bot> commented. Is it still unclear?

Comment: Web Applications SE is an English only site. Outside of the change of language this appears to be a duplicate of the [accepted answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/124442/).

Comment: Yes, it is a confirmation, just evidencing that using non-English interface might not help